# apply or loop rbeta using different alpha and beta values from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, apply, sapply

I'm trying to use sapply to create a matrix that contains output from rbeta using different specified alphas and betas obtained from a dataset. I think this should be fairly simple, but I am struggling.

Here is some data

```
q1 <- c(27, 104)
q2 <- c(25, 121)
q3 <- c(29, 114)
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(q1,q2,q3))
colnames(df) <- c('alpha','beta')
```

This is what I've done. Which is giving me 3 separate rbeta samples but I don't think its taking the correct values by row.  E.g. the first rbeta should be: `rbeta(I, 27, 104)`

```
I=10
rb <- sapply(1:3, function(x) rbeta(I, df$alpha, df$beta))
```

Can someone please clarify what I'm doing wrong here or point me in another direction?

Comment: `sapply(1:3, function(x) rbeta(I, df$alpha[x], df$beta[x]))`

Comment: @AllanCameron Amazing! Thank you. I knew it would be something silly like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply` on rows

```
set.seed(42)
apply(df, 1, function(x) rbeta(I, x["alpha"], x["beta"]))
             q1        q2        q3
 [1,] 0.1841086 0.1242001 0.1931461
 [2,] 0.2211195 0.1615636 0.2210664
 [3,] 0.2331062 0.1665653 0.1790950
 [4,] 0.2228934 0.1953668 0.2208726
 [5,] 0.2018876 0.1613773 0.2316363
 [6,] 0.2807989 0.2275919 0.2472799
 [7,] 0.2023407 0.1606147 0.1802312
 [8,] 0.3175574 0.1652301 0.2229498
 [9,] 0.2036065 0.2220179 0.1385964
[10,] 0.2680387 0.1564213 0.1738062
```

or using `Vectorize`

```
set.seed(42)
Vectorize(rbeta)(I, df$alpha, df$beta)
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
 [1,] 0.1841086 0.1242001 0.1931461
 [2,] 0.2211195 0.1615636 0.2210664
 [3,] 0.2331062 0.1665653 0.1790950
 [4,] 0.2228934 0.1953668 0.2208726
 [5,] 0.2018876 0.1613773 0.2316363
 [6,] 0.2807989 0.2275919 0.2472799
 [7,] 0.2023407 0.1606147 0.1802312
 [8,] 0.3175574 0.1652301 0.2229498
 [9,] 0.2036065 0.2220179 0.1385964
[10,] 0.2680387 0.1564213 0.1738062
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, we can use `Map` or `mapply` to provide arguments as vectors (or lists). If they don't match up in length, like the `10` in this case, elements getting recycled. `mapply` tries to simplify to a matrix, as `sapply` does compared to `lapply`. (NB: If you look at the source code of `Vectorize`, there's also `mapply` included.)

```
set.seed(42)
mapply(rbeta, 10, df[, 1], df[, 2])
#            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#  [1,] 0.1841086 0.1242001 0.1931461
#  [2,] 0.2211195 0.1615636 0.2210664
#  [3,] 0.2331062 0.1665653 0.1790950
#  [4,] 0.2228934 0.1953668 0.2208726
#  [5,] 0.2018876 0.1613773 0.2316363
#  [6,] 0.2807989 0.2275919 0.2472799
#  [7,] 0.2023407 0.1606147 0.1802312
#  [8,] 0.3175574 0.1652301 0.2229498
#  [9,] 0.2036065 0.2220179 0.1385964
# [10,] 0.2680387 0.1564213 0.1738062
```

Actually, you don't really need the data frame if you say

```
mapply(rbeta, 10, c(27, 25, 29), c(104, 121, 114))
```

Comment: Thanks Jay! I need the dataframe since I have more than just 3 values, but this is a helpful example.